# Week02 Homework 1

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I am getting type mismatch when I use traceIfFalse. What could be be reason? And how could I get this resolved. I also noticed that it didn't fail while I build lecture examples.

- Couldn't match expected type `PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.BuiltinString' with actual type` [ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.Char]'

  - In the first argument of `traceIfFalse', namely` "expected boolean True"'
    In the first argument of `($)', namely` traceIfFalse "expected boolean True"'
    In the expression:
    traceIfFalse "expected boolean True" $ (boolx == True && boolx == booly)
    |
    19 | mkValidator _ (boolx, booly) _ = traceIfFalse "expected 42" $ (boolx == True && boolx == booly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the OverloadedStrings Haskell extension.

Add `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` to the top of your file.